# Connect to SQL Azure from Azure Websites with EF 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am using the following `connectionstring` to connect my website from Azure Websites to SQL Azure and I am able to connect this locally and this is working with the Cloud App also. But it throws Login Failed when I connect from Azure Websites.

`<add name="sample" connectionString="metadata=res://*/dbModel.csdl|res://*/dbModel.ssdl|res://*/dbModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=tcp:server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=my_db;User ID=my_db_login@server;Password=**************;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>`

The error message is `The underlying provider failed on Open.`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get this working. While discussing this case on MSDN one member has suggested me to check the region of datacenters of services. My website was in the "eastasia" region and the cloud app & sql azure was in the "southeastasia" region. So, I've moved the other services to "eastasia" as Websites is not available in the "southeastasia". Anyway now it is working as expected.